# Unknown compiler option 'noStrictGenericChecks'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "types": ["node"]
    },
    "exclude": ["bin", "node_modules"],
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

[Code json file and build error visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHvW.png)

Comment: Not enough rep to comment... In the same boat - typescript is 2.4.2 but TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to update past 2.2.2: [screen cap of VS Extensions and Updates ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW3zJ.jpg) I believe this is the source of our pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `noStrictGenericChecks` flag was introduced as part of [TypeScript 2.4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/). Make sure you have the latest TypeScript version.

You can update your TypeScript version using if you are using globally installed TypeScript for compilation:

```
npm install -g typescript
```